# Trouble executing JQuery Flot from CGI script

Tags: jquery, python, cgi, flot

I'm currently testing a webservice on my local machine using Apache (on Windows XP).  I have a Python CGI script that calls the services and generates html output that can be viewed in a browser.  I recently came across Flot, which would enable me to plot my web service results.

So, I downloaded all the Flot libraries and dumped them into my Apache directory.  Everything seemed fine, because I was able to view the Flot examples successfully.  Unfortunately, when I try to generate similar html from my CGI script, the javascript seems to not execute.  However, if I take the html created by the CGI script and save it with a *.html extension, then reload it in the browser...it works.

Has anybody come across a similar problem?  Do my Apache settings/configuration need to be adjust to allows JQuery to execute?

Comment: What behavior are you seeing when it doesn't work? Any errors showing up in a firebug / web inspector console? It may be related to mime types, but hard to say w/out seeing it.

Comment: When the Flot graph doesn't load, everything else (just text) loads, and I'm left with a blank space where the graph should go.  This is b/c the Flot graph is embedded in a <div> tag.   I just installed firebug, never used it before...but in the "Console" pane, it throws an error that '$ is not defined' in '$(function() {', which is the javascript code given in the Flot example.  I tried removing '$' and the console gets no errors, but still no plot loading.

Comment: That most likely means that jQuery didn't successfully load into the document.  Try reloading the page while viewing the Net tab, and see if you're getting a 404 or similar when trying to load jQuery.

Comment: in the header of your page, jquery seems to be missing (no `<script src="jquery.js>`) you can use ctrl+u to check it, or firebug "ressoures" page

Comment: I figured it out... the problem was that the javascript libraries had to be put in the 'htdocs' folder.  Then, the javascript path in the html had to be adjusted such that it is relative to the 'htdocs' directory.

e.g.

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.flot.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... the problem was that the javascript libraries had to be put in the 'htdocs' folder.  Then, the javascript path in the html had to be adjusted such that it is relative to the 'htdocs' directory.

e.g.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.flot.js"></script>
```